# Tabs: Unexplained view behind inflated tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have a custom tab activity that I've put together using a lot of help from SO.  I am running into a couple problems however, that I can't find an answer to here.

Firstly, all the tabs states are coming from android apk tab resources of which I've adjusted the colors. The unselected tab nine-patch image is showing underneath each tab and I can't get it to go away, any suggestions?

Secondly, when I first go to the tab activity, the text of the focused tab does not change, but when I press the tab, or move to another tab and come back, the text changes.  How do I get the initial focus text to show as the focused text shows after a press?

Here are images to show what I mean; initial load on left, pressed on right, and both images show the unselected tab image showing behind the tabs:

I tried to post images of how the tabs look but my rep isn't high enough yet.  Sorry!

Here is the tab layout xml that I'm inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_tab_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTabIicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Active tab -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" 
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected"
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="false"/>

    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" 
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

And here is my activity java portion that inflates and displays each tab

```
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
// Team tab
View tabTeamIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_team_layout, getTabWidget(), false);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("teamTab");
title = (TextView) tabTeamIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tvTabTitle);
title.setText("Team Manager");
icon = (ImageView) tabTeamIndicator.findViewById(R.id.ivTabIicon);
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.custom_teamtab_icon);

spec.setIndicator(tabTeamIndicator);
spec.setContent(intentTeam);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help!  By the way, the colors look much better on the phones that I'm trying them on than they do in the emulator!!!

EDIT: Changed thread title

Answer (score 2):

Silly mistake here.  The xml layout that holds the tab widget had the

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_tab_selector"
```

attribute in it which was causing the background of the tabs to be drawn a second time in the background.